# Why does my perl one-liner ignore the first line of input?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to strip some content from an HTML file automatically, and I'm using the following command to strip everything up to the useful data:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 'undef $/; s/^.*?<pre>//s' $file
```

However, for some reason this leaves the first line of the HTML file (the DOCTYPE declaration) alone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By the time you `undef $/`, the first line has already been read. Use the `-0` option to set `$/` before anything has been read.

```
perl -p0i.bak -e 's/^.*?<pre>//s'
```

Comment: Supposing that the `-0` switch wasn't there you could do `-e 'BEGIN { undef $/ } s/^.*?<pre>//s'`.